# How to represent optional attributes in an ER diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

I know you can do the line/circle notation, but our lecture says we're not supposed to use those attributes. We're supposed to find a better solution. I've been reading the recommended database book, but the author DOES use the notation..? He doesn't seem to present an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Optional attributes](https://databasemanagement.fandom.com/wiki/E/R_Model:_Type_of_Attributes#Optional_attributes)*** can be represented with a dotted line connection to their respective entity. For example:[optional attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPeSO.png)

Comment: Required vs optional attributes do not have anything to do with relationships between entities. You can have a single table (entity) without any relationships with both required attributes and optional attributes. Required attributes are bolded in the Crow's Foot Model, whereas optional attributes are not bolded.